# Lazy once_cell causes stack overflow

Tags: rust

The code:

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

fn main() {
    const TEST: Lazy<[[u64; 64]; 512]> = Lazy::new(|| unimplemented!());

    TEST[0];
}
```

Results in the output:

```
thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\chess_ai.exe` (exit code: 0xc00000fd, STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW)
```

Weirdly enough only on windows. On Linux (WSL Debian GNU/Linux 9), the output is the expected:

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 23.38s
     Running `target/debug/chess_ai`
thread 'main' panicked at 'not implemented', src/main.rs:4:56
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Am I being a banana, lol? I don't understand at all what's going on here. This is also a pretty hard roadblock for me right now, so I really appreciate responses!

[Playground version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1a3e6c3f43406432b7fe9aa32e216239) works as expected.

### Versions

- `once_cell`: "1.12.0"
- `rustc` (both windows and Linux): "1.61.0"

Comment: `const` and `Lazy` together doesn't make any sense. You can think of `const` as the initializer being pasted every place the constant is used, which would defeat the purpose of initializing it lazily. Effectively anything with interior mutability (which `Lazy` would have) shouldn't be a `const`. Try `static` to see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: @kmdreko Same result. -- I mean the memory is constant, right? It's only initialized lazily. If not, I misunderstood that create (to be honest I would prefer the whole generation to be compile-time anyway, but there are some features I'm using that are not supported).

Comment: Constants are [in-lined at compile time](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html): "constants are inlined wherever they’re used, making using them identical to simply replacing the name of the `const` with its value". I don't know if that behavior would change for higher-order structs like the `Lazy`, but it would be possible that each time you use the `TEST` variable you get a new `Lazy` instance.

Answer (score 1):

So after some testing it seems like the stack is just not big enough to contain my variable, since this, plain, piece of code also results in a stackoverflow:

```rust
fn main() {
    let test: [[u64; 64]; 3000] = [[0; 64]; 3000];

    test[0];
}
```

Given that the `const` in the question is not really "generated"/"created" (lazy initialization) at compile time, it happens inside a stack-frame and most likely causes the stackoverflow.

Moving the data to the heap fixes the issue:

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

fn main() {
    static TEST: Lazy<Box<[[u64; 64]; 512]>> = Lazy::new(|| unimplemented!());

    TEST[0];
}
```

Seems like windows and Linux versions have different stack sizes, or the code is optimized differently.

Comment: `static` doesn't leave on the heap but on another memory segment, pre-allocated.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes, but the `Box` does, no? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html

Comment: Ah yeah, haven't seen it. Although it is redundant (unless the `static` is too big for the compiler to compile it).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yeah... it didn't really work like expected: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72503916/10315665